# How to get values of a table by ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a matter with this. I Have 2 this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> database = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();// to save each row into database
>ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>(); to save each line in to arraylist.
```

After that, I want to get a values into every column, like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 

a f b 4 5 5 

3 3 5 6 1 8
```

Expected I want is:

```
1 a 3

2 f 3
```

Here is my code:

```
String[] values = line.split(",");
for (String s: values )
rows.add(s);
database.add(rows;)
```

How could I do the get the expected result?

Comment: you tried anything ?

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] values = line.split(",")
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  database.get(i).add(values[i])
}
```